# Same JS external file, different html's, how to trigger different function when html's are loaded?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to ask is someone could help me out with this doubt:
I got an external .js file with all the functions I use in some website. There are also different html docs with different content, of course, and I want to invoke a function to update some content (the header and the selected items in some select fields within a form which aren't the same).
I know I can do this just using the onload event in the html body tag and calling different functions of the js file but I've read that's not the best approach, so my question is: how can I invoke different functions of the same js file from different html docs?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where did you read that that's not the best approach?

Comment: You could add a class to the `html` or `body` tag on your page and use that to target different pages with different code.

Comment: @artyom.stv I've seen that's not the best approach it in some webpages regarding 'non-intrusive' javascript. I believe it's a good choice to separate functionality and webpage's appearance.

Comment: @Gareth Please can you explain that option a little further? Thanks.

Comment: @Kaplan I've expanded on my comment in an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

file1.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<body>
....
<script src=file.js></script>
<script>
// some code
</script>
</body>
```

file2.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<body>
....
<script src=file.js></script>
<script>
// different code
</script>
</body>
```

You can also check the location or the DOM in your JavaScript but the above is as simple as it gets.

Other ways, in file.js:

```
if (location.href == 'something') {
    // do something
} else {
    // do something else
}
```

Or, using jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    if ( $('h1').text() == 'Main Page' ) {
        $('nav').hide();
        $('#welcome').show();
    } else {
        // something ...
    }
});
```

Comment: I'll have just three posible options regarding html's location, so the second option could be an easy approach. The third seems to be the smarter although I'm pretty novice with jQuery. Where can I get a jQuery API to take a deeper look into this library?

Comment: The jQuery API is documented at http://api.jquery.com/ but you may prefer to start from the tutorials at http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials — There is also the jQuery UI available at http://jqueryui.com/ which is a higher level themeable   user interface library based on jQuery. There are quite a lot of talks, presentations, podcasts and screencasts on jQuery and jQuery UI available to watch on the net so you may take a look at http://podcast.jquery.com/ or http://yayquery.com/ and google for the talks by John Resig and other videos on jQuery. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Page type 1:

```
<html>
    <body class="one">
    ...Markup...
    </body>
</html>
```

Page type 2:

```
<html>
    <body class="two">
    ...Markup...
    </body>
</html>
```

jQuery:

```
$().ready(function()
{
    ...code for all pages...

    if($('body').hasClass('one'))
    {
        ...code for pages of type 1...
    }
    else if($('body').hasClass('two'))
    {
        ...code for pages of type 2...
    }

    ...code for all pages...
});
```

I'm far from being a JavaScript guru, so I don't know how you might do this in pure JS.
As rsp says, you could also split your code into separate files - one for code that will be needed in all pages, and files with page specific code which are only loaded on the page where they're required.